# Record pageview date by php-ga

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I use php-ga to record data to Google Analytics from PHP script.
I have to set certain data of Pageview request. For example, I would like to tell GA that user opened the page yesterday or two days ago, but it always sets the date of my php-ga request as the date of pageview.

I attempted to set times of visits for visitor object:

```
$visitor = new GoogleAnalytics\Visitor();
$date = new DateTime($dateTime);
$visitor->setCurrentVisitTime($date);
$visitor->setFirstVisitTime($date);
$visitor->setPreviousVisitTime($date);
```

And to set the time of session start:

```
$session = new GoogleAnalytics\Session();
$date = new DateTime(dateTime);
$session->setStartTime($date);
```

But it doesn't help.

Do you know, is it possible to set date?

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of php-ga. I'm afraid Martin is right, Google doesn't accept dates that lie in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine you wouldn't be able to retrospectively set visit dates, otherwise I could log a million page views yesterday and go to advertisers with my Google Analytics data going, "Look how many visits I had! Now pay me big bucks if you want a banner on my site."

It's open to abuse.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually really easy with a little bit of php to make all sorts of fake page requests to google analytics. you could even do it client side to double our quadruple up your actual traffic, and have it come from a wide range of ips, instead of just the server ip.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using google analytics events and linking the events together?

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean? I create GA events from php script, but I can't set their time too.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstand your purpose.  If the user did something two days ago, why try to record it now, why not do it when they actually did it?